# get excel column type in java

Tags: java, excel

I need to convert an excel file to an access data base table. So I have a sheet with data grouped in table, i used Apache POI(*in java*) to read that sheet and then a would like to create an access table with those data. The problem is that i can't decide the attribute type for the CREATE TABLE statment... For example, I have an attribute called **article number**, that can assume only numbers or also letters, if I read the cell that contains only numbers it tells me that type is numeric but it is not so, because there are also a non numeric values... I don't know how to solve this issue... Thanks for your participation

Comment: Excel has no column type per se, there is only a cell type. You could iterate over all cells of a column and try to find the right datatype for access when you know all cell types.

Comment: So, the only one way is to iterate an entire column? But if it so, it becames so slowly, imagine that i have 30 000 + rows in my excel sheet

Comment: I know of no other and if you think about how excel works, then it may not deliver an appropriate result without more heuristics: If someone placed a comment in the cell below the column, you will receive a text type in the end.

Comment: In any way, thanks for answering my issue;))

Comment: I would not loop over all rows but only over a certain number of rows to guess the data type. SQL Server for example does the following: "The Excel driver reads a certain number of rows (by default, 8 rows) in the specified source to guess at the data type of each column. When a column appears to contain mixed data types, ..., the driver decides in favor of the majority data type..." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141683%28v=sql.120%29.aspx